# jQuery script: if one <div> clicked, apply action to two of them

Tags: jquery

I need some help to find the solution for my problem.

I have two multiple `<div>` tags. Let's say these are '.apple' and '.orange'. I have, let's say 3 apple and 3 orange. All the apples and oranges are numbered by their classes.

When I click specific '.apple', my jQuery script adds `'selected'` word to its class.

```
$('.apple1, .apple2, .apple3').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected').siblings('.apple1, .apple2, .apple3').removeClass('selected');
```

HTML-code looks like this:

```
<div class="apple1 selected"></div> <!--If .apple1 was selected-->
<div class="apple2"></div>
<div class="apple3"></div>

<div class="orange1 selected"></div> <!--If .apple1 was selected-->
<div class="orange2"></div>
<div class="orange3"></div>
```

What I want to do now is to find the way to add 'selected' to specific '.orange' class, depending which '.apple' was clicked. Like this:

```
.apple1 clicked => .apple1 class 'selected' AND .orange1 class 'selected'
.apple2 clicked => .apple2 class 'selected' AND .orange2 class 'selected'
.apple3 clicked => .apple3 class 'selected' AND .orange3 class 'selected'
```

I think I need an IF statement to do the job here, but I'm very new to jQuery and I can't figure out how to write the statement to grab which .apple (number 1, 2 or 3) was clicked and modify class of the same number orange.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Without seeing the HTML it's hard to know how to traverse the DOM, but as it stands right now I'm leaning towards a .find()

Comment: I've just added the HTML-code, you can check it out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor your HTML to use custom `data-*` attributes, and then use generic classes like `apple` and `orange` :

```
<div class="apple" data-number="1"></div>
<div class="apple" data-number="2"></div>
<div class="apple" data-number="3"></div>

<div class="orange" data-number="1"></div>
<div class="orange" data-number="2"></div>
<div class="orange" data-number="3"></div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(".apple, .orange").click(function() {
    var clickedClass = $(this).attr("class");
    var siblingClass = clickedClass == "orange" ? "apple" : "orange";
    var siblingNum = $(this).data("number");

    $(".orange, .apple").removeClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $("." + siblingClass + "[data-number=" + siblingNum + "]").addClass("active");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nrgft4L0/

Comment: I was about to suggest the use of data-* too, but @tymeJV beat me.

Answer (score 1):

First find the clicked element's class and grab the number contained. Then apply the 'selected' class both to the click and the respective '.orange' element:

```js
$(document).on('click', '[class^=apple]', function() {  
    $('div').removeClass('selected');  
    var i = $(this).attr('class').replace('apple', '');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('[class="orange' + i + '"]').addClass('selected');      
});
```

```css
.selected { color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="apple1">apple1</div> <!--If .apple1 was selected-->
<div class="apple2">apple2</div>
<div class="apple3">apple3</div>

<div class="orange1">orange1</div> <!--If .apple1 was selected-->
<div class="orange2">orange2</div>
<div class="orange3">orange3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly try the following.

```js
$('.apple1, .apple2, .apple3').on('click', function(event) {
  $('.orange' + event.target.id).addClass("active");
  $('.'+event.target.className).addClass("active");
})
```

```css
.apple1,
.apple2,
.apple3 {
  background-color: Red;
}
.orange1,
.orange2,
.orange3 {
  background-color: Orange;
}
.active {
  background-color: Blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="apple1" id='1'>asd</div>
<div class="apple2" id='2'>asd</div>
<div class="apple3" id='3'>asd</div>


<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="orange1">asd</div>
<div class="orange2">asd</div>
<div class="orange3">asd</div>
```